Central alignment of text node in a rectangle in Tikz drawing
I'm new to tikz and want put a text node at the center of a rectangle. Besides hard coding as below, is there any elegant way to make center alignment horizontally and vertically between the two objects like we used to do with WYSIWYG editor(e.g. the MS Office)? Thanks.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle +(3, 2);
  \node[draw=none] (hello) at (1.5,1) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You need to specify what "vertically center" a text means... Text has descendent and letters in fonts can have different heights. Do you want to align baselines of adjacent rectangles?

You can draw the rectangle as part of the node using option rectangle and the size options:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node[rectangle,draw=black,thick,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm] {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


or
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle,draw=black,thick,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm] {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

(same result).
I you want to draw the rectangle and the text with two commands you can alternatively replace your rectangle by a named node of the same size and use the name to add the text with a second node:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node[rectangle,draw=black,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum width=3cm,minimum
  height=2cm] (rect) {};
  \node at (rect) { hello };
  \node[red] at (rect.south west) { sw };
  \node[red] at (rect.south) { sw };
  \node[red] at (rect.south east) { se };
  \node[red] at (rect.east) { e };
  \node[red] at (rect.north east) { ne };
  \node[red] at (rect.north) { n };
  \node[red] at (rect.north west) { nw };
  \node[red] at (rect.west) { w };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Outside a tikz picture I would not use TikZ for it, but a \fbox around a \parbox:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox[c][2cm]{3cm}{\centering hello}}
\end{document}



Thank you. But I think my question is not described well.. the focus is not a text node, but a smaller object, like a circle in a rectangle.. I still accept the answer. Will repost another question.

@gpanda You can place other objects inside a named rectangle node the same as I've shown in the example with the red marks for north west, north, etc. This is the reason I've added this example. Try, e.g., \draw[blue] (rect.south west) -- (rect.north east); to see, how you can do it. And see the TikZ manual for more information about named nodes and how to position other objects relative to them.

Many thanks. I understand now. obj1 at (coordinates) means matching up the geometric center of obj1 with the point denoted by (coordinates). And obj1 at (obj2) means matching the geometric centers of the two objects, which makes them align with each other vertically and horizontally by default if no rotation setup. @cabohah

For this simple output, \fbox is enough, and the MWE is
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\fbox{\vbox to 5pc{\vfill%
\hbox to 7pc{\hfill Hello\hfill}%
\vfill}}%

\end{document}



Please don't use \vbox and \hbox in LaTeX (at least at the user level). Use, e.g.,  \parbox and \makebox instead.

This doesn't answer the question. It is for a task of a larger figure.

@gpanda Based on your question, have provided the suggestion, please make your question clear, if my suggestion not suits with you, then just leave it

Thanks to the answer by @cabohah
Now I can do this.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw=black}]
  \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm] (rect) at (0,0) {};
  \node[rectangle, draw=none] (hello) at (rect) {hello};
  \node[circle, minimum size=.8cm] (c1) at (rect.north west) {};
  \node[circle, minimum size=.5cm, draw=red] (c2) at (rect.east)[right=.2cm] {};
  \draw (hello) -- (c2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}


